# IF excel formula like =IF(C6>=70,"Pass","Fail") throws error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use a simple `IF` formula in a cell but I get `This is not a formula` error.

This is the `IF` I am trying (C6 is empty):

```
=IF(C6>=70,"Pass","Fail")
```

What I really need is a formula that calculate multiplication between two cells or empty cells depending on value of one of the two cells.
Something like:

```
=IF(G12=1,D2*G12,"")
```

Comment: use ";" instead of "," --> IF(C6>=70;"Pass";"Fail")

Comment: I get this in the cell: #NAME?

Comment: always use "=" before the formula, so the whole thing must be =IF(C6>=70;"Pass";"Fail")

Comment: I did, same result

Comment: do wou have german version? then IF is WENN

Comment: You got it. I have italian version and the function is SE. If you write an answer I will check it. Thank you. P.S. just excel could create function depending on user language, this is insane.

Comment: you are welcome, please accept the answer :)) as for the second part of your question, checking for an empty cell e.g.: =SE(G12=""; D2*G12; "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can be tricky sometimes. If your excel cell formula does not work always check the following first:

- do I have "=" in the first place
- is every string within quotation marks " "
- between every argument use ";"
- maybe there is another language dependent command